# Yocto recipe Busybox_1.23.2.bb fails at do_compile

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake, busybox

I am currently migrating from Poky Fido to Sumo. We have a few custom recipes in a separate layer (meta-user) which contains a busybox_1.23.2.bb recipe customized to the needs and derived from the Fido layer. After migrating to Sumo, I am trying to build this recipe, but now it fails at do_compile (Link to the log file is below).

https://pastebin.com/yYXJnC2e

Here is the Build Configuration:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.37.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal-4.8"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "arm-cortex-a8"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.5"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a vfp neon callconvention-hard cortexa8"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta-networking      
meta-python          = "master:45ee3c0e98bd3ed81419aaeae1e7324e486161a2"
meta-userbsp-ti        
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       
meta-user-common      = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
meta-oe              = "master:45ee3c0e98bd3ed81419aaeae1e7324e486161a2"
workspace            = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
```

NOTE: Host OS is CentOS_7.1

Both limits.h and byteswap.h don't exist in Poky-Fido as well, but compiles without problems, unlike on Sumo. Does this have to do with the wrong Toolchains used or due to glibc (FYI: glibc_2.27 is been used)? If it has to do with the Toolchains, which one should I be using and how do I go about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: /opt/ac500/yocto/branches/DEVEL_nextYocto/yocto/build_arm-cortex-a8/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.23.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/include-fixed/limits.h:194:61: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
 #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                             ^

Comment: In file included from include/libbb.h:13:0,
                 from include/busybox.h:8,
                 from applets/applets.c:9:
include/platform.h:152:11: fatal error: byteswap.h: No such file or directory
 # include <byteswap.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:198: applets/applets.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:373: applets_dir] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: /opt/ac500/yocto/branches/DEVEL_nextYocto/yocto/build_arm-cortex-a8/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.23.2-r0/temp/run.do_compile.16505:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /opt/ac500/yocto/branches/DEVEL_nextYocto/yocto/build_arm-cortex-a8/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/busybox/1.23.2-r0/

Comment: Share your complete error log in the question itself.

Comment: I did try that. But due to the fact that the log file has a lot of special characters, stackoverflow considers it as wrong formatting and gets really hard to format and post it in the question. Will try hosting the file and sharing the link

Comment: Use pastebin and share the URL